# how to convert selected string in list to integer python

Tags: python, string, list

this question is to convert selected strings in the list into integers.

However, this code converts the whole list into integer. 
how can i fix this ?

```
list = [['x', 'x', '1', 'x'], ['4', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', '2'], ['x', '3', 'x', 'x']]

def convert(str_list):
for i in range(len(str_list)):
    for j in range(len(str_list)):
        if str_list[i][j].isdigit():
            str_list[i][j] = int(str_list[i][j])
return(str_list)
```

edit: this code ^above also works. i edited it already!!
The output should be

> [['x', 'x', 1, 'x'], [4, 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 2], ['x', 3, 'x', 'x']]

Answer (score 0):

`map` this function to your list:

```
def str2num(s):
# Convert a string to an int, float, or stripped string

    try:
        return int(s)

    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(s)

        except ValueError:
            return s.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a string contains digits with [`.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit). So you can call `int` only if the element at that index contains digits:

```
def convert(str_list):
    n = 0
    while n < len(str_list):
        if str_list[n].isdigit():
            str_list[n] = int(str_list[n])
        n += 1
    return(str_list)
```

You can then loop over all lists in your main list and convert them individually:

```
lst = [['x', 'x', '1', 'x'], ['4', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', '2'], ['x', '3', 'x', 'x']]
for l in lst:
    convert(l)

print(lst)
```

**Output**

```
[['x', 'x', 1, 'x'], [4, 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 2], ['x', 3, 'x', 'x']]
```

Comment: okay but what if it's a list in a list?  Do i just for loop it?

Comment: @PeachhSalts if your list contains nested lists and you want to call `convert` on the nested elements as well, then you probably need to recursively call `convert` on them. Can you please update your question with an example like that any what you expect as output?

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension would be perfect for this, (also don't overwrite builtins!)

```
data = [['x', 'x', '1', 'x'], ['4', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', '2'], ['x', '3', 'x', 'x']]

def converted(str_list):
    return [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in data]
```

If you must use a while loop you can do this:

```
def convert(str_list):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for n in range(len(data[i])):
            try: data[i][n] = int(data[i][n])
            except: pass
```